# Multi-threading issue: uncaught exception Sys_error ("Bad file descriptor")

Tags: database, multithreading, ocaml

The given code is written in OCaml and implements a database system for reading data from a file and performing certain operations on it.

I am using Mutex to lock critical points, which happen to be when a thread tries to read data from a pipe and when a thread updates the mutable list of persons. I am unlocking readlock after the EOF and decrementing semaphore to ensure all threads are finalized.

The problem is that I am getting `Thread 42 killed on an uncaught exception Sys_error ("Bad file descriptor")` when I separately run the `read_from_file` function, but if I run the rock method, which itself runs the previously mentioned one, the output on the console is so slow.

```
type person = {
  firstn : string; 
  lastn : string; 
  age : int; 
  id : int; 
  salary : float option
}

let db = ref []
let readlock = Mutex.create ()
let writelock = Mutex.create ()
let semaphore = Semaphore.Counting.make 4

let read_from_file () =
  let pipe = open_in "/home/gc/ocamldir/ocamladv/lib/bigdata.csv" in

  let rec helper () =
    Semaphore.Counting.acquire semaphore;
    try
      Mutex.lock readlock;
      let input = input_line pipe in
      Mutex.unlock readlock;
      Mutex.lock writelock;
      let detail = String.split_on_char ',' input in
      db := {
        firstn = List.nth detail 0;
        lastn = List.nth detail 1;
        age = int_of_string @@ List.nth detail 2;
        id = int_of_string @@ List.nth detail 3;
        salary = None
      } :: !db;
      Mutex.unlock writelock;
      Semaphore.Counting.release semaphore;
      helper ()
    with
    | End_of_file ->
      Semaphore.Counting.release semaphore;
      Mutex.unlock readlock;
      close_in pipe
  in
  let rec create_threads count =
    if count > 0 then (
      ignore (Thread.create helper ());
      create_threads (count - 1)
    )
  in
  create_threads 4

let rock () =
  Thread.join (Thread.create read_from_file ());
  !db
  |> List.filter (fun {age; _} -> age < 18)
  |> List.filter (fun {firstn; _} -> String.length firstn < 6)
  |> List.iteri (fun counter {firstn; lastn; id; _} ->
         ANSITerminal.print_string
           (
             [ANSITerminal.Background ANSITerminal.Cyan;
              ANSITerminal.Foreground ANSITerminal.Red]
           )
           (
             Printf.sprintf "\nIllegal account: {%d} " counter
           );
         flush stdout;
         ANSITerminal.print_string
           (
             [ANSITerminal.Background ANSITerminal.Cyan;
              ANSITerminal.Foreground ANSITerminal.Blue]
           )
           (
             Printf.sprintf "full name: %10s %10s id: %5d" firstn lastn id
       ))
```

I think that problem lies in `read_from_file` function but was not able to find it!

Answer (score 1):

Bear in mind that I'm an ocaml beginner, so check what I say makes sense, but...

You open your file-handle outside the threads

```
  let pipe = open_in "/home/gc/ocamldir/ocamladv/lib/bigdata.csv" in
```

But then you try to close the handle at the end of each thread's run:

```
    with
    | End_of_file ->
      Semaphore.Counting.release semaphore;
      Mutex.unlock readlock;
      close_in pipe
```

So - if you have 4 threads there is a good chance one finishes before the others and closes your file-handle. The next thread tries to read and rather than getting an `End_of_file` exception gets the bad filehandle instead because it is closed.

I *think* what you probably want is something like this where you create the reader threads.

```
  let rec create_threads count ts =
    if count > 0 then (
      let t = (Thread.create helper ()) in
      create_threads (count - 1) (t::ts)
    )
    else ts
  in
  let worker_threads = create_threads 4 [] in
  List.iter Thread.join worker_threads;
  close_in pipe
```

I'm guessing `Thread.join` is the right thing to do to wait for the workers to exit before closing the file you opened earlier.